# using virtual machine like mySql server

Tags: mysql, macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

i'm developing a java program and i need a database. 
Now i'm using MAMP and it's pretty easy but i would have a virtual machine (ubuntu server)
and i need to connect my java program with this virtual machine using vitualBox.

the situation:

- I installed VirtualBox on my mac and I installed an ubuntu-server machine
- set "bridge adapter" in the network settings of VB
- I installed mysql on ubuntu-server and i created a simple database (all work well by ubuntu)
- doing ifconfig by ubuntu I get the ip: 192.168.1.217

so in the java program i made this function:

```
public static Connection connect(String host, int port, String dbName, String user, String passwd)
{
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    try
    {
        String dbString = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        dbString = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbString, user, passwd);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Failed to connect with the DB");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dbConnection;
}
```

and in the main() i use:

```
Connection con = connect(1, "192.168.1.217", 3306, "Ciao", "root", "cocacola");
```

3306 was a default value. I don't know if is correct, it works on mamp, but…. how I can find
the correct port that I have to use with VB?

when I ran the program I get the catch excepion… what's wrong?

Comment: Java code appart... Can you actually connect to the database server using your favourite MySQL client?

Comment: You're going to have to: 1) forward ports in virtualbox and 2) open up that port in the ubuntu firewall.  It might be better to just run mysql on the mac?

Comment: @Alvaro G. Vicario: no i can't

Comment: @trojanfoe: thanks, how can i do it?
in virual box i don't find something for opening the post

Comment: @trojanfoe - I don't know if it is off topic - simply because at present, it's likely to be both a coding issue and a computer set up issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `/etc/my.cnf/` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file for the bind_address.
Your MySQL binds to localhost by default, you should put it to 0.0.0.0.

Find:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Replace:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

If you don't have a my.cnf file, you can create it. In that case, you would need at least this:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: hi, i do what you say and now i have a different error:
Failed to connect with the DB
java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '192.168.1.77' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Comment: You'll need to add correct permissions for the user you're connecting as. If you're connecting as user "root", that would be something like this: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.77';`. You'll need to execute this locally on your ubuntu VM, so in terminal connect with `mysql -u root -p` and execute it there.

Comment: now the error is: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.77' (using password: YES)

Comment: Try executing your script without a password. There was no password associated with the root user for this IP. So MySQL hasn't allocated one with the GRANT. You can also use this with your password:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.77' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';`

Comment: thanks a lot! it works!!!
i ''tik'' your answer!

a little question: if i restart the router the ip change, so i should 
add a new connection.. there is a way to baypass this stuff?

Comment: You could add the GRANT to `'root'@'192.168.%'`, where % is a wildcard. :-)

Comment: perfect ;)

to be precise also using PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.77' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password', if i run the program with the password i get the error.. but is not a big deal :)

Comment: Well, in order to clean the GRANT's we've been adding you could do `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'root'@'192.168.1.77'`. It's probably the multiple access definitions with/without password that are clogging your access table now. If you have a commandline mysql terminal open, you can issue `SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user;` and then check `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';` for each 'user'@'host' (sadly there is no show-all).

Answer (score 0):

Your method takes the wrong parameters. Compare

```
public static Connection connect(String host, int port, String dbName, String user, String passwd)
```

with

```
Connection con = connect(1, "192.168.1.217", 3306, "Ciao", "root", "cocacola");
```

This means, when you create the string dbString you are creating

```
jdbc:mysql://1:192.168.1.217/3306;
```

However, you overload doesn't even match, so I'm amazed you've gotten this far (although I do C# not Java so maybe this is OK)! The Connection connect takes 5 parameters, yet when you call the method, you pass 6!

I think change

```
Connection con = connect(1, "192.168.1.217", 3306, "Ciao", "root", "cocacola");
```

to

```
Connection con = connect("192.168.1.217", 3306, "Ciao", "root", "cocacola");
```

Comment: He can't even connect using his favourite MySQL client, so he's got connectivity issues anyway.

Comment: @trojanfoe Agreed. Although how did he get as far as the try catch when the signature doesn't match (is this a Java thing?)

Comment: No idea.  Often people don't even post the real code...